# In R want to connect to a remote server and read a file

Tags: r

In R I want to connect to a remote server and read a file. I am using

```
scp("host", "file path", "password", user="username")
```

It is returning

> could not find function scp

Comment: you have to use the `RCurl` library: `library(RCurl)` first

Comment: Perhaps this question could be improved by modifying it to, "How do I use scp after connecting to a remote server in R?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scp` function is provided as part of the RCurl package. If you haven't done so already, install the latest version of the package:

Open an R terminal and execute the following command to install it:

```
R> install.packages("RCurl", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If it asks about using a personal library, enter `y`

You will then be prompted to select a mirror. Just pick a location somewhat near you for a hopefully-quicker download speed.

Now, at the top of your R script calling scp, add the following line:

```
library("RCurl")
```

this will allow you to use `scp` in your R script.